# Mousedown not working on Iphone?

Tags: javascript, ios

I am try to make a mousedown function work on ios however cant seem to fix the issuse. I know the problem is with the code below any help would be greatful!

```
 bindInteractions: function(){
        // bind interactions used during live play
        this.playfield.on('mousedown','touchstart', _.throttle(_.bind(function(event){
            this.fireGun();
            var weaponSpread = this.player.getWeapon().getSpread();
            if(weaponSpread <= 0) {
              console.error("Zero spread weapons can do no damage. Recommended minimum size: 25");
            }
            var playfieldOffset = $(event.delegateTarget).offset();
            var location = {
                top: event.pageY - playfieldOffset.top,
                left: event.pageX - playfieldOffset.left
            };
            $.each(this.liveDucks, function(i,duck){
               duck.shotsFired(location, weaponSpread);
            });

        },this), this.player.getWeapon().getReloadTime()));
        this.showLevelInfo();
    },
    unbindInteractions: function(){
        // unbind interactions that should not be available during transitions and other non live play states
        this.playfield.off('mousedown','touchstart');
        $.each(this.liveDucks, function(i, duck) {
            duck.unbindEvents();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about `.on()`

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )**
>
> **events**
>
> Type: String One or more space-separated event types and
>   optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

It says `One or more space-separated event types`.

So maybe your `mousedown`and `touchstart` should be in the same string parameter :

```
this.playfield.on('mousedown touchstart', _.throttle(_.bind(function(event){

}
```